# CSS Background Images Cropped Off in Firefox after Zooming Out

Tags: css, firefox

I'm having an issue in Firefox (Mac and PC) with CSS background images and setting the zoom level to below 100%.

The background image seems to be getting pixels cropped off either at the right or bottom of the image.

Here's a link to a bin to show what I mean: http://jsbin.com/ehORakU/1 - if you go in Firefox and then zoom out (either to 90% or 75%) you should be able to see the issue.

If not, here's what I'm seeing:

100% Zoom Level:

[image]

90% Zoom Level:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom pixel of the icon is being clipped off, even though the image is only 16x16 and the container div is 18x18.

I've also seen this behavior in IE, but am unable to reliably replicate it.

Any ideas on how to prevent the edge pixels of the image from being clipped on zoom out in FF?

Comment: In test 4 (http://jsbin.com/ehORakU/4/edit), I've attempted to use the `image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;` property. While this does fix the edge problem at 90% zoom, it goes back to getting clipped at 75% zoom.

Comment: It's a known issue, and unfixable from a webdevver perspective. Let Mozilla developers figure it out, there's a ton of bugs on issues like this.

Comment: FireFox has many problems with scaling. For one thing, it cannot scale fonts continuously (i.e. it jumps from one fixed size to another) and getting decent dropcaps become a cross-browser nightmare. It also messes up borders by one pixel or so. I'm not surprised it botches picture scaling too. Some guy at Mozilla seems to hate floating point numbers.

Comment: Though it isn't a CSS solution, I believe I can remedy the issue by adding 1 pixel of space in the image itself, so that the icon no longer touches the edges but has some empty space around it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
#icon {
  background-size: 100%; /* or background-size: cover; */
  padding-bottom: 0.1em /* seems to be better too */
}
```

It's like Firefox remove background-size property when zooming in / out...

Comment: Tried that here: http://jsbin.com/ehORakU/2 (100%) and here: http://jsbin.com/ehORakU/3 (cover). Firefox still cuts off when zooming out.

Comment: Quite better on my computer with background-size: 100%. Anyway I think you need a hack for that...